# Непереведенный комментарий (в советах по расширенному поиску)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, поиск

Смотрел советы по расширенному поиску, заметил, что при наведении курсора на `inquestion:1234` отображается комментарий (краткое описание) на английском.

> [image: Скриншот места дефекта]

Comment: Use the delay, Luke: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL0PX.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подхватил старый перевод с небольшим изменением:

> Искать ответы на вопрос
>      (или используйте опцию «inquestion:this» на странице вопроса)

Будет на сайте после обновления Transifex и пересборки сайта.